# Problem in sorting alphabetically a linked list in C

Tags: c, linux, sorting, struct, linked-list

i'm trying to sort alphabetically a linked list in C. The linked list i used is the following:

```
struct lineList{ //structure with all the line of the input file
    char *line;
    struct lineList *next;
};
typedef struct lineList llist;
```

I saved into the string `line` some path taken from this file:

```
/home/user/Scrivania/find/try
/home/user/Scrivania/find/try1
/home/user/Scrivania/tryDir
```

Then i tried to sort them alphabetically with this portion of code:

```
char *line;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t line_size;

llist *lHead = NULL;
llist *lTail = NULL;

FILE *fInput;

fInput = fopen(inputFile, "r"); //the file that contains the path of the file in which search.

if(fInput == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s, exiting. . .\n", inputFile);
    exit(1);
}

while((line_size = getline(&line, &len, fInput)) != -1){
    //saving into the lineList structure
    llist *l = malloc (sizeof(llist));
    l->line = line;
    l->next = NULL;
    //sort alphabetically
    if(lHead == NULL || strcmp(l->line, lHead->line) < 0){
        l->next = lHead;
        lHead = l;
    } else {
        lTail = lHead;
        while((lTail->next != NULL) && (strcmp(l->line, lTail->next->line) >= 0)){
            lTail = lTail->next;
        }
        l->next = lTail->next;
        lTail->next = l;
    }
}
fclose(fInput);
```

In the variable `inputFile` is stored the path of the file showed above. If i try to iterating through the list and printing out the content of `line` i always get the last path of the file:

```
/home/user/Scrivania/tryDir
/home/user/Scrivania/tryDir
/home/user/Scrivania/tryDir
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you not to use `qsort` from the standard library?

Comment: Actually i'm new to C programming and i don't even know this function. How is it working? @gkpln3

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Comment: There are some previous questions about sorting a **linked list** to be found from a [search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c+stackoverflow+sort+a+linked+list).

Comment: I think it is a problem with your string handling.  Seems like you are using the same line for all entries.  try copying the chars from line into the node instead

Comment: Yes you're right, i edited the question with the solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Although posting your own answer within the original post is not inherently evil, it is a little squishy,.  (At least within the stack exchange sites.)  It would be more idiomatic to post the answer as a separate post in the answer section, then accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this. I'm new here @ryyker

Comment: @gkpln3 - you cannot `qsort` a linked list. You can create an array-of-pointers to the nodes in the list and `qsort` that, but otherwise there is no guarantees (and in fact there is no expectation) that list nodes will be sequential in memory to allow sorting by `qsort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some problem with string handling. To solve the problem I changed the line assignment in this way:

```
 llist *l = malloc (sizeof(llist));
l->line = (char*)malloc((strlen(line)+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(l->line,line);
l->next = NULL;
```

The sorting was correct, the string assignment was the problem.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there might be a small period of elapsed time required before the site will let you accept an answer, so if you have already tried, come back in a few minutes to try again.  Good job!

Comment: The site says that I have to wait 2 days before accept the answer. So i come back here in two days. Thank you so much for the tips @ryyker !

Comment: Your `malloc` size is off by one byte, because you need space for the nul terminator at the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `qsort` from the standard library.

The following is an example on how to use it.

`void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main () {
   int n;

   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   qsort(values, 5, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {   
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: How should i use this in my program?

Comment: Where is the linked list which is mentioned in the question?

Comment: I showed the list at the beginning of the question. @WeatherVane

Comment: Er, that is an array, not a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Comment: Anyway, can you please show me how can i sort that? I don't get how should i do.

Comment: @ryyker Oh okay, in fact, I didn't get why _Weather Vane_ was telling that the struct at the beginning of the question is an array...  Thank you so much for the information!

Comment: @ryyker that's right, since my query refers to a linked list in the *question*, I was asking where a linked list is in this *answer*. I didn't notice that OP answered, mybad.